# Installjammer build on windows launch on linux

Tags: installation

Hi
 I want to use Install jammer in windows machine to build an application and launch the installer in linux. How to do it. I am new to this Installbuilders. Some one please help me

My basic requirement is need to install tomcat server on linux machine and then launch a java application on that. The build shpuld be done on windows and the launch is on linux.

Answer (score 1):

InstallJammer will let you build any platform from any other platform right out of the box.  You shouldn't need to do anything more than download the Windows installer, install it and go build your project.

Note that when you're building your new project, the project wizard will choose only the current platform by default, so accepting all of the defaults will create a project built for Windows.  You just need to select Linux as a platform when you create the project, or you can activate the Linux platform later after the project is already built.